# How to find the earliest score and time recorded from 4 columns of score and time?

Tags: r

I Have edited my data and pasting the output from dput()

```
structure(list(PersonID = c(111, 222, 333), ScoreOne = c(1, 3, 
NA), ScoreOneTime = structure(c(1654147200, 1654148400, 1654149600
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), ScoreTwo = c(3, 
NA, 1), ScoreTwoTime = structure(c(1654137960, NA, 1654146000
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I have two types of scores recorded with time for each person. I noticed two scores has been recorded for same person with different time, I want to find out earliest type of score recorded with time and create a 2 new column assigning the type of score and time in R. i am learner in R

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible, please try running `dput()` on your data and paste the output here.

Comment: i have edited and pasted the output from dput()

Comment: Something like `library(dplyr); your_data |> mutate(which_first = ifelse(ScoreOneTime < ScoreTwoTime, "Score One", "Score Two")`?

Comment: I got it right with above code, and how can we create a separate column of "first score" and "first score time" from above code.